# Reactor opening and total time to reach a specific temperature

Tags: temperature, flow, gas

Let's say I have a reactor (we assume that its shape can be approximated by a horizontal cylinder) in which there is air at the temperature of 1000K and at pressure of 1.5 bar. Now, I want to open it to the open air and let it cool down. I guess that the first thing that will happen is that there will be a gas flow from the reactor to the open air until the pressure equalize with the atmospheric pressure.

**My question is** : How can I calculate the total time that it takes for the reactor to be at a temperature T < 1000K?